# windows 7 is no longer prompting me when opening a cmd prompt

Tags: windows-7, uac

i'm not complaining, just observing.. Windows 7 is no longer prompting me when opening a cmd prompt.

My UAC setting seems to be default

[image]

I open a cmd prompt start..cmd I get no prompt so one might think it's not running with administrative privileges.

But I can create a file on `c:\`

Why would that be?  What setting is it that would cause that lack of a prompt?

[image]

Comment: turns out the touch command wasn't making that file. i'll delete my question

Comment: If it is a admin command prompt it will say "Administrator Command Window" at the top of the command window.

Comment: the question is resolved. The assumption of the question was flawed. It wasn't creating the files...

Answer (score 1):

cmd.exe and powershell both execute as a standard user by default on win7. You may set them to always request elevation by going to `c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe` and right clicking -> `Properties -> Compatibility -> "Run this program as an administrator"`. I do this every build. I wish MS would provide a `sudo` equivalent for cli.

If you are able to create a file in the root of C, confirm your permissions on the drive.

What you are likely seeing is a feature of UAC called [virtualized folders](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista), which redirect writes to `c:\` into the standard users `%appdata%` directory. Sometimes this [causes problems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387). If the touch command did not return an error, check your `%appdata%` for the new file.

You can verify whether a process is running in high or standard integrity mode with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), by enabling the column "Integrity Level". See here for definitions on the [Integrity level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) property. A standard user creates Medium integrity processes by default. If the process is running as "High integrity" or "System", then it is running with administrative powers.

My guess is, that your prompt is running in Medium Integrity mode, and your touch command's output was redirected to `%appdata%`. That is why the create appeared to succeed, but the file was not present when you used another utility to view the contents of `c:\`

Comment: The question was why can I write to `c:\`  that is nor normal is it. See my second screenshot.. anyhow.. i'll make a comment.. to my q..

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt does not always launch with administrative privileges. Your screenshot indicates that `cmd` was launched with regular (non-admin) privileges.

If you created a shortcut for `cmd`, you can change the shortcut properties so the command-prompt always launches with [administrative privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plRLd.png).

Alternatively, and probably a better option is to use a keyboard shortcut to launch an application with administrative privileges. Select the application icon (in Start menu, Windows Explorer or on your Desktop) and then press Control+Shift+Enter. You should then get the familiar UAC prompt.

By default (at least in some versions of Windows), the built-in Administrator account runs all applications with full administrative privilege. Have a look at these [UAC-related group policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Ooy.png).

Comment: I do not understand what you are getting at here. I showed in my second screenshot that I could write A FILE, to root. IIRC, That isn't normally possible when you have UAC on and you didn't get prompted,  is it?

Comment: This depends on your filesystem permissions. Usually, members of Users group have read-only permissions, while Administrators have full permissions. Also, usually the title for a command-prompt session running with elevated privileges reads "Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe". Also, by default the local Administrator account runs all applications with administrative privileges.

Comment: It Was Not Running With Elevated Priv.  And I Was Not Local Administrator (note- one isn't meant to use that account post xp). anyhow, see the comment to my q.